# Jekyll blog post and github

Tags: jekyll, blogs, github-pages

I have some problems with seeing blog posts on github.

[image: This is my blog]

When I clicked on the blogs site, this is what happened

[image: This is the error]

Can someone help me out ? The blog works perfectly fine on local host but not on github site. I'm grateful.
This is my website : blog-kiettran.com
This is my github repo : https://github.com/khtran1994/my-jekyll-blog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `url:` config setting seems to be incorrect.
Changing it to match your `CNAME` should resolve this..

```
url: http://blog-kiettran.com
```

See your post here: http://blog-kiettran.com/jekyll/simple-blog.html

Comment: Ok I see that. Thank you for your help